# How to remove GRUB selection?

Tags: 10.10, server, grub2

I was trying to find `/boot/grub/menu.lst` OR `/boot/grub/device.map` as usual on Ubuntu Desktop or other versions  to change the GRUB selection, but there is no file `munu.lst` or `device.map` in the grub directory. Where can I find GRUB's configuration file? to modify the grub selection

Comment: I can't follow what exactly you are trying to remove, but you are using GRUB2, not GRUB. Its configuration file is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but unless you provide more details, it's difficult to give you advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you need is `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub` after you've made your changes.

Comment: Or just `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, that's the file that gets generated when you run `update-grub`. Anyway, your way indeed is better as otherwise your `grub.cfg` would be reset every time `update-grub` is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [GRUB Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10340183#post10340183) if you'd like to work w/ a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

sidenote : Ubuntu 10.10 will keep grub-legacy if you upgrade from a previous ubuntu distribution but install by default grub2 otherwise. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 has information about both upgrading grub-legacy -> grub2 and reverting grub2 -> grub-legacy if you happen to experience problems with the new approach.

otherwise, yeah. /etc/default/grub is the place where you now need to check. Note that the "automagic options" system has completely changed, too.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Spy on this, please: [Grub-Customizer (How to fix your dual-boot in case you miss the right boot option)](https://askubuntu.com/q/39477/15945)