# How to change font size and/or screen resolution in Virtual Terminals TTYs 1-6...?

Tags: command-line, fonts

The default font size in the **non**-X terminals is too small for me.
How can I changed it permanently ?

I've ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` in TTY 1, but seems to only effect the 'gnome-terminal' running courtesy X in TTY 7...

**UPDATE** ... I've just checked more carefully... It actually *did* changed the font, from 8-14 (it only offers 8 14 and 16).. The width of each char did not change; they only got taller (ie. fewer lines on the screen) ...
I'm getting **160** characters across the screen (on a 17"CRT). That makes it impossible for me... So it seems like it may be a screen resolution issue, and not a font issue (unless I can choose a larger font size somehow)

So the question is now.. Either: How do I change the font size to larger than offered by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`  ... Or: How can I reducet the screen resoluton of TTYs 1-6 ?

Answer (score 7):

You can force your TTYs to run in different resolutions and font sizes by adding `vga=xxx` to your boot line. `xxx` should be replaced by any of these values:

```
Colours   640x400 640x480 800x600 1024x768 1280x1024 1600x1200
--------+-----------------------------------------------------
 4 bits |                  0x302      
 8 bits |  0x300   0x301   0x303    0x305    0x307     0x31C
15 bits |          0x310   0x313    0x316    0x319     0x31D
16 bits |          0x311   0x314    0x317    0x31A     0x31E
24 bits |          0x312   0x315    0x318    0x31B     0x31F
32 bits |
```

<sub>Some of these do not work on some hardware. When it fails you will be presented with a list of alternatives.</sub>

edit: [hwinfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hwinfo) [image: Install hwinfo] can show you scancodes you can use with the following command:

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer | grep Mode
```

Resolution = columns, lines:

```
640 x 400 = 80 x 25
640 x 480 = 80 x 30
800 x 600 = 100 x 37
1024 x 768 = 128 x 48
1280 x 1024 = 160 x 64
1600 x 1200 = 200 x 75
```

To make it permanent you can add the `vga=xxx` to your bootloader options. The file you need in 11.04 is `/etc/default/grub` and you need to run `sudo update-grub` after any changes (from: [How to remove GRUB selection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25407/how-to-remove-grub-selection) ).

Comment: I've tried every which way, but the right way, it seems..  eg.. I added `vga=0x314` (and tried `=314`) as the last line in `/etc/default/grub`... ran `sudo update-grub`.. and nothing changes.. I still have 160 characters across the screen when I press Ctrl+Alt+F1... I'm using 10.04 (which I believe grub 2.. but one of your links said that although vga=xxx is depricated, it should still work in grub2..  Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: I will have a go at this soon! my notebook so my new one needs settinng up 1st ;)