# Grub-Customizer (How to fix your dual-boot in case you miss the right boot option)

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

Have you ever installed **Grub-Customizer**? Yes, it's a nice tool for rearrange our boot system and gain some extra space in the discs. Very usefull though!

But, as i recomende that you install this usefull app, at the same time i advise you to be carefull, because any distraction and your dual boot simply could go away!

And how can we fix this as an easy way?

1. Boot your cd (as you did before) with your Ubuntu (if you have latest version installed in your pc it doesn't matter if you boot another version of ubuntu. If you have Natty 11.04 you can simply use your 10.04 cd...)
2. try the experiment mode (you don't need to install ubuntu again!)
3. Then install (as you have made in your system) Grub-Customizer packages (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer && sudo apt-get update)
4. in update manager select the option "open source code software (Universal)"
5. In the terminal again, install the repository packages (sudo apt-get install grub-customizer)
6. Acess to Grub-Customizer and select your root. Then your boot option (in case you have dual or triple boot) will appear and you can select again and treat a big headache...

Very simple.

Hope you liked it!

Jorge

Comment: Welcome to Ask, more Jorge's are always welcome! Please edit your question so that it's only a question, and then post a seperate answer that answers the question.

Comment: ok... I'm a new guy here!!! :D

Comment: Great guide Jorge Pinho! Setting it up as a Question, and then a separate Answer post just makes it easier for newbies to the site who are looking for answers to understand how the site works. It just keeps everything consistent :) I like this a lot though! I have never heard of this application and will keep it in mind.

Comment: MArco Ceppi, I would like to propose you to prove that what i'm saying is rethorical!? Can you prove that? I don't think you can because i did it myself and it worked. I recomend you to consult Daniel Richter web site (if u don't know who he is, he's a Linux developer and he created this package "Grub-customizer". Am i saying some rethorical, vague, incomplete or rethorical thing!?